# website inside website - no redirection or leave the first site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website and I want to run another website inside on it.Is that possible?I don't want to exit my website  or redirect me to the new website. I want to be in the same page with that. I have seen some similar questions but I didn't find an answer that I get my result.Can I have on my website another website?I want to use on my website Xsolla basically and to be able to do some things on that site.I don't want to go somewhere else or redirect me.I want in my site to have that site.

Comment: `<iframe>`... but I wouldn't recommend it in most situations

Comment: if you can give me an answer on it to try